# How to collect logs file form s3 ? elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've enable log files rotations to amazon s3, every hour amazon create file "var_log_httpd_rotated_error_log.gz" for every instance at my elastic beanstalk environment.

first question :
the log files will not overlap ? so every time amazon save the file at s3, it also delete it from the instance and create a new one ! right ?

second question :
How could I collect all that files, I want to build a sever that collect all that files and enable me to search for text at those files !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That is what rotating means. It stops writing to one file and begins writing to a new file.
2. If they are being uploaded to s3, you can write code to download and index those files. Splunk or Loggly may help you here.